# Tool to verify magento missing patchs

Tags: api, security, patches, installation, application

I want to **scan magento missing patches** in my laravel 5.2 application. How can I do that?

Comment: What is this for? Scanning sites you don't own for missing patches sounds shady. Otherwise see: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/132478/243

Answer (score 0):

There's several *tools* you can use in my opinion, I'm not a Laravel developer so I'm not entirely sure if that matches you needs:

- [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com/) is an online service that lets you check a Magento website and gives you an output of what patches are not installed on this website
- there is [a Magento module developed by Philip Jackson](https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AppliedPatches) that checks what patches have been applied to a Magento store. I reckon you could probably customize it to be able to check what patches are missing.