# Magento CLI options to check Security patch applied or not?

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, cli

Is there any CLI options to check security patch is applied or not ? How many are pending.

I have tried with online tool magereport and many of patch status is unknown. That is why am asking for a CLI option , that can check better.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't specifically a cli tool but you can check the contents of app/etc/applied.patches.list. This will give a list of patches applied and files changed. Using cli `cat app/etc/applied.patches.list` from your magento root directory.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/integer-net/DevDashboard - it is not a CLI script, but an open source module that shows this information based on `etc/applied.patches.list` and the Hypernode API. You could take the code and build a CLI script around it if you like.

[image: screenshot]

***Disclaimer:*** I wrote it

Comment: Seems like a good candidate for a magerun command too :-)

Comment: Definetely something that's worth a work. Anyone started something already?

Answer (score 0):

On top of what Andrew said, Philip "Winkle" Jackson developed a module that lets you check the applied patches from the backend: https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AppliedPatches

Answer (score 0):

There is extension that is checking all security paches installation from the back end and do many other security checks. Magefence - https://www.extensionsmall.com/mage-fence-security.html